# php - array not outputting all values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a small issue i can't seem to work around. i have some data i'm pulling from the database and before i display the data, i want to manipulate some values in there. here's my function handling these:

```
public function getPageContent($id) 
{
    $menutopic_model = new Menu_Topic();
    $content = $menutopic_model->getAllContent($id);

    //var_dump($content);        

    $data = array();

    foreach ($content as $value)
    {
         $title = explode(',', $value->title);
         $filename = explode(',', $value->filename);

         $data['topicname'] = $value->topicname;
         $data['title'] = $title;
         $data['filename'] = $filename;

    }    

   //var_dump($data);

}
```

Now, when i dump `var_dump($content);`, i get the entire array of data as it should be:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#346 (3) {
      ["topicname"]=>
      string(19) "Signs giving orders"
      ["title"]=>
      string(42) "Stop,No entry,No cycling,No motor vehicles"
      ["filename"]=>
      string(179) "DQP0GVcUA2dG8ZfqeVYLO68YodgYnJMOjJw2o2iC.png,vWUcHGX3VVKPT08JXh9mAqZ40pT0vfDJ78Yoqovz.png,bplX8bbwHzHKX9n6SvvQiYNhkWwKxi2bhsrQ94U2.png,8KAEovxQn3EgzHoZg1euSgNYTFupnLdKusJ4SIEP.png"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#345 (3) {
      ["topicname"]=>
      string(13) "Warning Signs"
      ["title"]=>
      string(111) "Road narrows ahead both sides,Road narrows on right (left if symbol reversed),Crossroads,Junction on bend ahead"
      ["filename"]=>
      string(179) "uZ7fnDjlYfKU3pdSQ7wAq4siFryA6jSEitmRyPhp.png,4pslo6cC0I2E606DscWxiDD3sCBW7ZGaESQES4r0.png,xdVBMpV6PTLtX48M67kfWOqy59rsYMDZMuWbqDwl.png,hLtIGikARgARqmSqit4mqNXRFJthipH6O5vqxlbN.png"
    }
  }
```

but after passing the data through the foreach, this `var_dump($data);` only returns the last item in the array:

```
array(3) {
  ["topicname"]=>
  string(13) "Warning Signs"
  ["title"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(29) "Road narrows ahead both sides"
    [1]=>
    string(47) "Road narrows on right (left if symbol reversed)"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "Crossroads"
    [3]=>
    string(22) "Junction on bend ahead"
  }
  ["filename"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(44) "uZ7fnDjlYfKU3pdSQ7wAq4siFryA6jSEitmRyPhp.png"
    [1]=>
    string(44) "4pslo6cC0I2E606DscWxiDD3sCBW7ZGaESQES4r0.png"
    [2]=>
    string(44) "xdVBMpV6PTLtX48M67kfWOqy59rsYMDZMuWbqDwl.png"
    [3]=>
    string(44) "hLtIGikARgARqmSqit4mqNXRFJthipH6O5vqxlbN.png"
  }
}
```

what should i change in the above to get the correct result?

Comment: This happens because everytime you set for example `$data['topicname'] = $value->topicname;` -  which will always gonna be the last item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reusing the same array occurance each time round the loop. So create your array and then add it asa new occurance to the real array

```
public function getPageContent($id) 
{
    $menutopic_model = new Menu_Topic();
    $content = $menutopic_model->getAllContent($id);

    //var_dump($content);        

    foreach ($content as $value)
    {
        $title = explode(',', $value->title);
        $filename = explode(',', $value->filename);

        $d = array();
        $d['topicname'] = $value->topicname;
        $d['title'] = $title;
        $d['filename'] = $filename;

        $data[] = $d;
    }    

   //var_dump($data);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were getting only last value just because you were over-writing values in array with the below code, which you were using.

```
$data['topicname'] = $value->topicname;
$data['title'] = $title;
$data['filename'] = $filename;
```

**Changed code:**

```
public function getPageContent($id) 
{
    $menutopic_model = new Menu_Topic();
    $content = $menutopic_model->getAllContent($id);      

    $data = array();

    foreach ($content as $value)
    {
         $title = explode(',', $value->title);
         $filename = explode(',', $value->filename);

         $data[]=array(
             'topicname'=>$value->topicname,
             'title'=>$title,
             'filename'=>$filename);
    }    

     //var_dump($data);

 }
```